# Filterable with BaseAdapter to AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying create a BaseAdapter with Filterable to my AutoCompleteTextView. I have an object with name Local, and I add some attributes to this object for example: `new Local("Guaira"); new Local("Franca"); new Local("Barretos"). If I type text "Guaíra" the popup does not open to select "Guaira", but if I type "Barretos" is open and "Guaira", "Franca" and "Barretos" are shown. I can't understand why doesn't works.

How could I do it ?

**AutoCompleteTextView**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/acCidade"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:hint="Cidade"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    />
```

**BaseAdapter**

```
public class CidadeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    private Context context;
    private List<Cidade> lista;
    private Filtro filtro;

    public CidadeListAdapter(Context context, List<Cidade> lista){
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public void clearList(){
        lista.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Cidade cidade = lista.get(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.estado_cidades_listadapter, parent, false);
            viewHolder.llEstadoCidades = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llEstadoCidades);
            viewHolder.tvEstadoCidade = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEstadoCidade);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.tvEstadoCidade.setText(cidade.getCidade());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filtro == null){
            filtro = new Filtro();
        }
        return filtro;
    }


    //holder pattern
    private static class ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout llEstadoCidades;
        TextView tvEstadoCidade;
    }


    /** filtro de autocomplete */
    private class Filtro extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = lista;
                results.count = lista.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<Cidade> nCidade = new ArrayList<Cidade>();

                for (Cidade c : lista) {
                    if (c.getCidade().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){
                        nCidade.add(c);
                    }else{
                        nCidade.clear();
                    }
                }

                results.values = nCidade;
                results.count = nCidade.size();

            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Use**

```
List<Cidade> listaCidade = new ArrayList<Cidade>();
listaCidade.add(new Cidade("Guaira"));
listaCidade.add(new Cidade("Barretos"));
listaCidade.add(new Cidade("Franca"));
listaCidade.add(new Cidade("Ituverava"));

actvCidades = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.acCidade);
actvCidade.setAdater(new CidadeListAdapter(this, listaCidade));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a second list which will contain all the filtered entities.

In the publish method you can assign the filtered values to that list.

Let that filtered list be the source for the `getView(..)` method.